# How to return data from promise inside JSON object? angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

This is my first time when I try to return data from promise inside JSON object and I stuck with this task

So common way is something like this

service js

```
 app.factory("dataService", ["$http",
    function ($http) {
      function getData(id) {
        return $http.get('endpoint', id)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data
            });
    }

   return {
     getData: getData
   }

}])
```

controller js

```
$scope.data = {}

dataService.getData($routeParams.id)
   .then (function (res) {
        $scope.data = res
    });
```

this works fine and everybody is happy

now I'm trying to assign data inside object

controller js

```
 angular.forEach($scope.properties, function (item) {
                      $scope.data.properties.push({
                          order: item.number,
                          name: item.name,
                          value: item.value,
                          items: $scope.getProp(item.id)
                      })
                  });

 $scope.getProp = function (id) {
            return dataService.single(id)
                .then (function (res) {return res});
        };
```

service js

```
function single(id) {
            return $http.get('endpoint' + "/" + id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data
                })
        }
```

and now I'm getting JSON object with promise and $$state inside

I understand the nature of this problem but solution for this problem is out of range of my knowledges, so could somebody help me deal with it ?

Comment: @4castle so you suggest me to use callback ?

Comment: The `push` statement should be inside a callback function of `$scope.getProp(item.id).then`

Comment: @4castle got you, thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. Also, your code doesn't currently have this issue, but be cautious that you don't add to the list that you're currently iterating, or else you might get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it work is:

```
$scope.data.properties = [];
var promiseList = $scope.properties.map(function(item) {

    var promise = $scope.getProp(item.id);

    return promise.then(function (data) {
        var newItem = {
            id: item.id,
            order: item.number,
            name: item.name,
            value: item.value,
            items: data
        };   
        $scope.data.properties.push(newItem);
        return newItem;
    });
});

$q.all(promiseList).then(function(itemList) {
    console.log(itemList);
    //More code here
});
```

The above example creates a list of promises that return objects that have the `items` property populated with data from the promise returned from `$scope.getProps`.

In addition it pushes each populated item to scope. Because the asynchronous XHRs may not complete in the order that they were started, the scope list may not be in the same order as the original.

The [$q.all method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) however will wait for all the XHRs to complete and return the list in the original order.